# vsftpd ubuntu issue

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

I have installed vsftpd on ubuntu 10.04

When I login using ip , username and password then I straight go to home directory of user.

Is there any way that I can

1. Make separate user for only ftp
2. When they login via ftp, they should see the mounted drive i,e /media/shared_drive only not their home directory
3. They have all read and write access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://alien2thisworld.net/sitePages/tutorials/vsftpd_virtual_users_setup.html

I think this link covers what you want.  You can accomplish #2 with symbolic links. #3 you'll have to set user permissions for the directories in question, I think.

Answer (score 0):

symbolic links may not work properly, because they cannot be followed outside of a chroot jail.

instead, you can just mount the directory you want with the option "--bind" :

```
# mount --bind /media/shared_drive /home/ftp/pub
```